# Why does GeoServer (UI) not refresh the layer after a succesfull REST PUT?

Tags: geoserver, rest

- I have a layer configuration in Geoserver (`space1:my_layer`) which I want to change.
- I change the layer via REST PUT on http://localhost/rest/workspaces/space1/datastores/store1/featuretypes/my_layer
- Afterwards I do a GET on the same URL and the configuration is changed. Perfect.
- Then I launch the UI / web of GeoServer and then still my old configuration is shown there. No matter if I (hard) refresh the page, it doesn't update.

Is there a commit needed? or a refresh? is the REST response more right than the web response? Why should I do?

Comment: which part of your layer are you changing? do you have browser caching turned on or off?

Comment: Hi @IanTurton, I update the SQL query of an SQL view by updating the entire set of metadata entries. In the meantime I found out that it just takes sometime to see the changes. Is there a caching involved for the UI part of Geoserver? (browser caching is off by using chrome's debugger).

Comment: a POST to `/rest/reload` does the job of updating the UI, but why does the web ui take so long? and not the wfs / rest json

Comment: there is probably some caching in there to save time - in general you should avoid using the GUI and REST at the same time